# Webmethod returning nothing in webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to webservice thing, what I am trying to do in below is pass variable in method and get data from sql from different tables in a class...but for some when run this code, I don't see my webmethod...any help is greatly appreciated..sooner the better as I am stuck and have to deliver something tomorrow...

```
namespace Webdata


{ 
public class Data : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    class Record
    {
        public Char DESCRPTN_104 { get; set; }
        public Char PMDES_01 { get; set; }
        public Char PRTNUM_10 { get; set; }
        public Char ORDRef_10 { get; set; }
        public DateTime TNXDTE_01 { get; set; }


    [WebMethod]
   static List<Record> GetData(string ORDNUM_10)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=******;Integrated Security=true;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Account_Types.DESCRPTN_104, Part_Master.PMDES1_01,Order_Master.PRTNUM_10,Order_Master.ORDNUM_10,Order_Master.ORDRef_10,Part_Master.TNXDTE_01 FROM (****.dbo.Order_Master Order_Master LEFT OUTER JOIN ****.dbo.Part_Master Part_Master ON Order_Master.PRTNUM_10=Part_Master.PRTNUM_01) LEFT OUTER JOIN ****.dbo.Account_Types Account_Types ON Part_Master.ACTTYP_01=Account_Types.ACTTYP_104 WHERE Order_Master.ORDNUM_10 = '" + ORDNUM_10 + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            records.Add(new Record()
            {
                DESCRPTN_104 = dr.GetChar(0),
                PMDES_01 = dr.GetChar(1),
                PRTNUM_10 = dr.GetChar(2),
                ORDRef_10 = dr.GetChar(3),
                TNXDTE_01 = dr.GetDateTime(4)
            });
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        return records;
    }}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "run your code", you mean query the service for what actions it implements, by "returns nothing", you mean the service claims it doesn't have any, and the code you posted is exactly the code you're trying to compile, then I'm guessing you don't see your WebMethod because you didn't specify an accessibility level for your method, and the default is private. WebMethods should all be public.

Comment: I changed the webmethod to Public as you suggest...but now am getting GetData method error in webmethod..which says...Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebService3.Service1.Record>' is less accessible than method 'WebService3.Service1.GetData(string)' C:\Sharepoint Stuff\MRR_InfopathForm\WebService3\WebService3\Service1.asmx.cs 62 35 WebService3

Comment: @user2344306 If you get an error, the first thing you should do is google it. That error says that you're trying to return a list of objects of a class that you defined, Webservice3.Service1.Record, and that that class isn't marked public. If you want to return something from a public function, the thing being returned has to also be public, or how would you use it?

Comment: @user2344306 For someone who was in such a  hurry to get an answer, you sure don't seem to be in a hurry to say whether the answer worked by accepting it :p. (Or even saying whether it's working now...)